# Layer's feature color (Leaflet map)

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

How can I assign a color for each feature without defining the attribute value?

Problem: I have many features, I don't want to define the ID values manually when calling `getColor()` like this:

```js
function getColor(x) {
    return x === "ID1" ? "black" :
           x === "ID2" ? "blue" :
           x === "ID3" ? "red" :
    }
```

I thought I should create an array for the ID and assign a color based on the index

```js
var ID = []
to collect the id from the layer, I did this:
var id_collection = L.geoJson(data)
            id_collection.eachLayer( function(layer){
            ID.push(layer.feature.properties.id)});
```

Now, the var ID contains all ID.

Then, I want to visualize the data and assign a color based on the index of the ID variable. Like this:

```
function getColor(x){    
    return x[0] ? "red": //first feature 
           x[1] ? "blue": //second feature
           x[2] ? "black": //third feature    
 // and so on until complete all ID
}

Layer = L.geoJson(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: getColor(ID)
        });
        return marker;
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

This way returns all markers as "red" color.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "without defining the attribute value". Please edit your question and explain the logic of assigning colors to features. Random color? Unique random color?

Comment: @TomazicM I mean assigning color based on the index of an array. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's still not clear. What array? How do you get/calculate index in `getColor` function? Please edit your question and clarify this.

Comment: @TomazicM I updated the question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create markers with the option `color: getColor(ID)`, all features will  have the same marker as the `ID` variable in the global scope doesn't change during loop. What you should do is call `getColor(feature.id)` here.

If you want to loop color based on index, your `getColor` should be like this:

```
function getColor(ID) {
  var colorList = ['red', 'blue', 'black']
  return colorList[ID % colorList.length]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `id` from feature properties to `getColor` function and then find index of that `id` in array `ID`. Color selection would also be easier then if colors would be stored in an array.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var color = ['red', 'blue', 'black'];
function getColor(id){
  var i = ID.indexOf(id);
  var color = ((i >= 0) && (i < colors.length)) ? colors[i] : 'white';
  return color;
}

var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      color: getColor(feature.properties.id)
    });
    return marker;
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: thank you for your useful contribution!